# Haskell: makeLenses - data constructor not in scope

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I have this simple code here to define a type and use `makeLenses` to generate lenses.

```
module Api.Jira.Types.Search
  (
    SearchRequest(..)
  ) where

import GHC.Generics
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Aeson (FromJSON, ToJSON)
import Control.Lens
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Types

data SearchRequest = SearchRequest
  { _jql :: T.Text
  , _startAt :: Maybe Int
  , _maxResults :: Maybe Int
  , _fields :: Maybe [T.Text]
  , _expand :: Maybe [T.Text]
  , _properties :: Maybe [T.Text]
  } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance ToJSON SearchRequest where
  toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions {
             fieldLabelModifier = drop 1 }

instance FromJSON SearchRequest where
  parseJSON = genericParseJSON defaultOptions {
                fieldLabelModifier = drop 1 }

makeLenses SearchRequest''
```

This results in the error:

> Data constructor not in scope:
>           SearchRequest''
>             :: template-haskell-2.11.1.0:Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.Name
>       • Perhaps you meant one of these:
>           ‘SearchRequest’ (line 20), variable ‘searchRequest’ (line 39)

I have found two somewhat related problems on SO, but they are related to declaration order and don't seem to apply here, since all types contained in `SearchRequest` are already defined.

- [Haskell: Template Haskell and the scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20876147/haskell-template-haskell-and-the-scope)
- [Type synonyms "not in scope" when using Template Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979147/type-synonyms-not-in-scope-when-using-template-haskell)

Any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `''SearchRequest`, not `SearchRequest''`.

Comment: Haha ouch. Well, that's embarrasing... Thanks for the quick response, I'll accept once the time limit expires.